# How do I get a song's artist, album, and cover art from AVURLAsset in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8.1, avurlasset

I want to extract album name, artist name, cover art, and duration from a song using `AVURLAsset` in iOS 8.1.

So far I have:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[strSongPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
```

What are the details to put in after this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you already checked `audioAsset.commonMetadata` ?

This property will return an array of all available `AVMetaDataItem` objects for your initialized asset.

Each item is representing exactly one available metadata property of your asset